# Diagram of education in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands

How would the dutch educational system be represented in a diagram? Or put differently, what are the different roads that lead to the academic world in the Netherlands?

PS. This question ("What are the different roads to get into academics in the Netherlands?") came up in chat awhile ago, so I drew a diagram and it was suggested I share it as a self answered post as well, because it's a neat resource. Didn't do it back then as some parts lacked, but somebody asked me the same question more generally again so looked up the diagram, finished it and wanted to share it publicly now after all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about academia.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: This falls directly in a category that has been defined as on topic, namely: "Requirements and expectations of academicians". Specifically in this case 'requirements of academicians in the Netherlands'. Or considered in a different way, preparations for a non-academic career are explicitly off topic, thus implicitly making preparations for an academic career on topic.

Comment: And for that matter, how is this too localized. As I pointed out I have received multiple questions for this and searching for "Diagram of education in the United States" will result in similar diagrams which have helped me **a lot** in understanding the US system. Some existed for the Dutch system as well already, but the semi-good ones were dutch and all the english ones were downright incorrect or sorely lacked detail.

Comment: For that matter, if somebody feels up to drawing more of these for their own country: I for one would **love** seeing them and would definitely give them an upvote. Even the US ones I have seen are extremely confusing, for example: according to [the few](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Education_in_the_United_States.svg/2000px-Education_in_the_United_States.svg.png) that include community colleges it would be possible to enroll in the middle of an undergraduate program (or 1-year under graduate program) after you finish (which as far as I know isn't true).

Comment: @DavidMulder: Actually, it's relatively common in the U.S. to receive a two-year degree from a community college and then complete a four-year undergraduate degree with two more years of study at a university.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: Dutch Educational System]

PS. I have only been part of the Dutch system for the first 8 years, but I know it pretty well as I know a lot of Dutch people, still I might have made mistakes. If so: apologies.

Comment: This is very nicely done. I'm just curious about the three-year masters. I've never heard of those. Which fields are those in?

Comment: @Ana The only two I know of are medicine and a combination master of theology and pastoral care at Groningen. I am sure there must be more, though the rule of thumb is 2 years for research masters an 1 year for more vocational/humanity like masters.

Comment: Can you explain what the numbers are on the right? I assume they're age, but it's not too clear.

Comment: Is "Continued Scientific Education" the right name?  Presumably not all education is vocational or scientific.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: Well, depends on which definition of scientific you follow. But yeah, pre-bologna University was strictly academic/scientific whereas HBO wasn't even a lower level but strictly vocational. For example, the Netherlands only had a handful of universities, but every single one of them ranked top 200. In contrast to for example the UK where all old polytechnics are universities now as well and as an outsider you have no idea about the quality.

Comment: @Compass Typical starting age indeed.

Comment: I just mean that in English "scientific" would be specific to the sciences (biology, chemistry, physics, etc.), while for example "academic" would be much broader (including history, literature, etc.).

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician Well, even in English the word 'sciences' can be used more broadly than those 3. After all, you do have terms like 'human sciences' as well. Or in the words of Wikipedia Collaborators "In an older and closely related meaning, 'science' also refers to a body of knowledge itself, of the type that can be rationally explained and reliably applied.". But I do know the confusion that the word can cause, even the word academic is used in surprisingly many different ways.

Comment: VWO means _voorbereidend_ wetenschappelijk onderwijs, not _voortgezet_, so it should be "Preparational Scientific Education", not "Continued". It's supposed to prepare for university.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich You're absolutely right... I always thought that the V in HAVO was the same as in VWO. Shame on me. And right now I don't have access to a full fledged computer to edit the image. If anybody has a graphics editor and could copy the word "Preparatory" from VMBO and throw it into the VWO box on top of "Continued" that would be really great! And otherwise I will do it... in the future at some point.

Comment: "PhD students aren't students". Yes and no, this needs clarifications. They're a bit like _trainees_, so I wouldn't say they are not students and tend to have tight social connections with 'other students (non-PhD)'

Comment: Oh and 2 year master is mostly normal, at least for STEM. 1 year is normal for humanities

Comment: And, due to recent regulations, a few of the horizontal arrows (regrettably) have been either removed or thinned. But a nice graphic, I think I'll improve and use this for an answer 'soon'. Oh and the arrows do go both ways, you know

Answer (score 3):

There are similar diagrams and descriptions of educational systems for the Netherlands and other European countries here:

http://eacea.ec.europa.eu/education/eurydice/

Comment: Oh! I have seen some of those diagrams before, didn't know where they were from. Can't say I think they are all that clear or good, *but* the sheer quantity makes it an extremely worthwhile resource :D .